# How to detect if the NSDictionary item is an integer?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary object with 2 items, the first one is a NSString and the second is an Integer. When I loop into the dictionary items I'd like detect what of they is an Integer.

What is the best way to do it?

The current dictionary is:

```
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"San", @"name", @"123", @"id", nil]
```

Comment: You got few answers below, but this approach does not look “right”. Why are you trying to detect integers?

Comment: to mount sqlite queries on the right way, e.g. when the value is an integer I can't put the value between "'", but if it's a string I need use "'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you are putting in the dictionary is in no way an integer, it's a NSString which only contains numbers. Why not just use a NSNumber object and use it the way it should be?

```
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"San", @"name", @123, @"id", nil]
```

This uses a literal for a NSNumber.

Comment: Ok, but how can I detect into loop if the current value is an integer?

Comment: @GodFather - isKindOfClass

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isKindOfClass:` to check if an object is of a specific class and `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` to analyze every object contained in a dictionary.
For example:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name": @"San", @"id": @123};
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        NSLog(@"%@: %@ is a number", key, obj);
    else
        NSLog(@"%@: %@ is NOT a number", key, obj);
}];
```

The first line is a `NSDictionary` creation using literals, the same is for `@123`, which automatically insert a `NSNumber` with 123 value in the dictionary.